# Accessing Express Session Variables in views

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am trying to access the session variables in EJS views. But not able to do that
Below is the code

```
var express=require('express');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var db=require('./models/db.js');

var routes=require('./routes/route.js');
var user=require('./routes/user.js');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');

var session=require('express-session');
var cookieParser=require('cookie-parser');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var app=express();

app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret:"qazwsxedcrfvtgbyhnujm"}));


app.get('/',routes.home);
app.get('/register',routes.register);
app.post('/createUser',user.doCreate);
app.get('/login',routes.login);
app.post('/authenticate',user.login);


var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var server=app.listen(port,function(req,res){
    console.log("Catch the action at http://localhost:"+port);
});
```

Here is the login handler

```
    exports.login=function(req,res){

    var username=req.body.username;
    var password=req.body.password;

    User.findOne({username:username}, function(err,user){

      if(err){
        console.log("Error : Please enetr valid username and password");
        res.redirect("/login");
      }

     user.comparePassword(password,function(err,isMatch){
       if(isMatch && isMatch==true){
         console.log("Authentication Suucessfull");
         req.session.username=user.username;
         res.render("/",{username:req.session.username});
       }else{
         console.log("Authentication UnSuucessfull");
         res.redirect("/login");
       }

     });

    });
  }
```

In the EJS view I am trying to print the username that is set by the login handler

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Awesome</h1>
                        <% if( typeof(username) !== 'undefined' ) { %>
                        <h1><%=username%></h1>
                        <%}%>
                        <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Try `console.log(user)` and see that mongoDB is returning what you think it is, an object with a `username` property

Comment: Thanks @adeneo got it , everything was fine just messed up a bit. Got it working now, console.log() is good for debugging. Will Keep in mind

Comment: But when I use res.redirect() to redirect the user to home page after successful login it says undefined redirecting to '/'. Can't we send some data with redirect like **res.redircet("/",{username:req.session.username});**

Comment: Can't we access session data directly in EJS views rather than attaching the data while redirecting, as I'm doing above

Comment: No, you'd have to add that to the route that outputs `/` as well

Comment: Keep in mind that 'findOne' does not raise an error if no user is found but returns null as response. Additional for checking if there's an error you should check if the response object is set.